How does a banking motion affect the pitch and yaw?
I'm trying to model the turning of an airplane, specifically banking. So, I want a pitching motion to change the actual pitch and yaw of the airplane based on the level of roll. For example, if the plane has not rolled, pitching it will turn it directly up, but if there is some degree of roll, the plane will turn somewhat up and somewhat to the side.
Right now I'm using a matrix transformation to rotate the model, and the order I'm using makes pitch and yaw independent of roll - so, I need to figure out how roll will affect the pitch and yaw when the plane banks.
Here is what I have tried:
if (keys["arrowleft"]) {
  plane.roll -= 0.1;
}
if (keys["arrowright"]) {
  plane.roll += 0.1;
}
if (keys["arrowup"]) {
  plane.pitch -= 0.1*Math.cos(plane.roll);
  plane.yaw -= 0.1*Math.sin(plane.roll);
}
if (keys["arrowdown"]) {
  plane.pitch -= 0.1*Math.cos(plane.roll);
  plane.yaw -= 0.1*Math.sin(plane.roll);
}

In other words, is there any way to convert a pitching motion while rolling (given current orientation) to proper Euler angles with an elementary formula? Or do I need to use a different matrix transformation?

The (not so useful) normal way to rotate things
All pitch, roll, and yaw operations rotate your plane's orientation vector, so left/right shouldn't add a fixed value to the plane's roll, they should instead roll the plane by some angle, which you apply to your orientation vector by multiplying it with a 3D rotation matrix.
Now, "normally" if your plane orientation vector is ordered as p, r, y then rolling is a rotation over r:
|  cos(a)  0  sin(a) |   |p|
|    0     1    0    | x |r|
| -sin(a)  0  cos(a) |   |y|

And, similarly, pitching means rotating over p, so
|  1     0       0    |   |p|
|  0   cos(a) -sin(a) | x |r|
|  0  -sin(a)  cos(a) |   |y|

And then you can update the plane's position by storing and applying rotation values as you're flying along... but this approach means you're going to run into the extrinsic vs. intrinsic problem, where the order of operations can change the final orientation, and doing things like applying a change over more than one axis (which is approximately "all the time" in a flying game) can be a right pain in the butt.
The much more useful way to rotate things
We can solve problem by, instead, tracking the plane's "current local system of axes" rather than tracking angles, and rotating those axes based on key input (where we perform a roll as "a rotation in the current pitch/yaw 2d plane", and perform pitching as "a rotation in the current roll/yaw 2d plane")
That's a little more work, but not a crazy amount of work. We implement the following matrix instead:
| x * x * (1-cos(a)) +     cos(a),  x * y * (1-cos(a)) - z * sin(a), x * z * (1-cos(a)) + y * sin(a) |
| x * y * (1-cos(a)) + z * sin(a),  y * y * (1-cos(a)) +     cos(a), y * z * (1-cos(a)) - x * sin(a) |
| x * z * (1-cos(a)) - y * sin(a),  y * z * (1-cos(a)) + x * sin(a), z * z * (1-cos(a)) +     cos(a) |

Where x, y, and z are the axis in our current local coordinate system that we want to rotate over. E.g. if we want the plane to roll:
[x, y, z] = normalize(localFrame.roll)

And of course, that looks lengthy, but it's programming so there's a whole bunch of repeated terms that we can just precompute to save some cycles and make the code easier to read:
sa = sin(a), ca = cos(a), mc = 1 - ca
xsa = x * sa, ysa = y * sa, zsa = z * sa
xmc = x * mc, ymc = y * mc, zmc = z * mc

    | x * xmc +  ca,  x * ymc - zsa, x * zmc + ysa |
Q = | y * xmc + zsa,  y * ymc +  ca, y * zmc - xsa |
    | z * xmc - ysa,  z * ymc + xsa, z * zmc +  ca |

So let's see that in action: the following runnable snippet lets you focus on the interactive graphic it sets up, and your arrow keys let you roll and pitch the plane's local coordinate system (without drawing the plane to make things as clear as possible).


function sourceCode() {
  let step = 0.05;
  let localFrame = {
    roll: [-1, 0, 0],
    pitch: [0, 1, 0],
    yaw: [0, 0, 1],
  };

  function setup() {
    setSize(400, 150);
    setBorder(1, `black`);
    noGrid();
  }

  function draw() {
    setCursor(`none`);
    clear(`white`);
    translate(0.5 * width, 0.7 * height);

    // draw our local axes
    const f = 100;
    const scale = v => ([v[0] * f, v[1] * f, v[2] * f]);
    const p0 = project(...[0, 0, 0]);
    const px = project(...scale(localFrame.roll));
    const py = project(...scale(localFrame.pitch));
    const pz = project(...scale(localFrame.yaw));

    setStroke(`red`);
    line(p0, px);
    setStroke(`green`);
    line(p0, py);
    setStroke(`blue`);
    line(p0, pz);
  }

  // matrix * vector function
  function mul(M, v) {
    let x, y, z;
    if (v.length === 3) {
      x = v[0];
      y = v[1];
      z = v[2];
    } else {
      x = v.x;
      y = v.y;
      z = v.z;
    }
    return [
      M[0] * x + M[1] * y + M[2] * z,
      M[3] * x + M[4] * y + M[5] * z,
      M[6] * x + M[7] * y + M[8] * z,
    ];
  }

  // "update our local frame" function
  function update(a, name) {
    const pv = localFrame[name];
    const m = pv.reduce((t, e) => t + e ** 2, 0) ** 0.5;
    pv.forEach((v, i, pv) => (pv[i] = v / m));

    // rotation matrix for new pitch axis
    const [x, y, z] = pv;

    const sa = sin(a), ca = cos(a), mc = 1 - ca;
    const xsa = x * sa, ysa = y * sa, zsa = z * sa;
    const xmc = x * mc, ymc = y * mc, zmc = z * mc;

    const Q = [
      x * xmc + ca,  x * ymc - zsa, x * zmc + ysa,
      y * xmc + zsa, y * ymc + ca,  y * zmc - xsa,
      z * xmc - ysa, z * ymc + xsa, z * zmc + ca,
    ];

    // apply rotation
    localFrame.roll = mul(Q, localFrame.roll);
    localFrame.pitch = mul(Q, localFrame.pitch);
    localFrame.yaw = mul(Q, localFrame.yaw);
  };

  // key handler
  function keyDown() {
    if (keyboard.ArrowLeft) {
      update(-step, `roll`);
    }
    if (keyboard.ArrowRight) {
      update(step, `roll`);
    }
    if (keyboard.ArrowUp) {
      update(-step, `pitch`);
    }
    if (keyboard.ArrowDown) {
      update(step, `pitch`);
    }
    redraw();
  }
}


// load the code once the custom element loader is done:
customElements.whenDefined(`graphics-element`).then(() => {
  document.getElementById(`graphics`).loadFromFunction(sourceCode);
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/graphics-element/5.0.0/graphics-element.js" type="module"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/graphics-element/5.0.0/graphics-element.min.css" />

<graphics-element id="graphics" title="Manipulating a 3D coordinate system"></graphics-element>



Just remember that your flight surfaces incur a bit of an angle too, so when you're rolling, you generally need to add a bit of global (rather than local) yaw every frame, too.
Adding realistic banking: progressive global yaw
We can add a simple "value transform" that adds some global yaw based on how much we're rotating over the roll axis in a turn() function that we run as part of our game loop:


function sourceCode() {
  let step = 0.05;
  let rotation = 0;

  let localFrame = {
    roll: [-1, 0, 0],
    pitch: [0, 1, 0],
    yaw: [0, 0, 1],
  };

  const aLen = 100;

  function d(v) {
    return ([v[0] * aLen, v[1] * aLen, v[2] * aLen]);
  }

  function updateLocalFrame(M) {
    localFrame.roll = mul(M, localFrame.roll);
    localFrame.pitch = mul(M, localFrame.pitch);
    localFrame.yaw = mul(M, localFrame.yaw);
  }

  function setup() {
    setSize(400, 120);
    setBorder(1, `black`);
    play();
  }

  function draw() {
    clear(`white`);
    translate(0.5 * width, 0.7 * height);
    drawAxes();
    drawPlane();
    turn();
  }

  // Apply some global yaw based on how much we're rolling:
  function turn() {
    const a = rotation / 15;
    const sa = sin(a);
    const ca = cos(a);
    const R = [
       ca, sa, 0,
      -sa, ca, 0,
        0,  0, 1
    ];
    // apply global rotation
    updateLocalFrame(R);
  }

  function drawAxes() {
    const p0 = project(...[0, 0, 0]);
    setStroke(`red`);
    const px = project(...d(localFrame.roll));
    line(p0, px);
    setStroke(`green`);
    const py = project(...d(localFrame.pitch));
    line(p0, py);
    setStroke(`blue`);
    const pz = project(...d(localFrame.yaw));
    line(p0, pz);
  }

  function drawPlane() {
    const {
      roll: x,
      pitch: y,
      yaw: z
    } = localFrame;
    const Q = invertMatrix([x, y, z]).flat();

    let poly = [
      [-50, -10, 0],
      [50, 0, 0],
      [-50, 10, 0],
    ].map(v => project(...mul(Q, v)));
    plotData(poly, 'x', 'y');

    poly = [
      [10, -40, 0],
      [10, 40, 0],
      [-10, 50, 0],
      [-10, -50, 0],
    ].map(v => project(...mul(Q, v)));
    plotData(poly, 'x', 'y');
  }

  // "update our local frame" function
  function update(a, name) {
    const pv = localFrame[name];
    const m = pv.reduce((t, e) => t + e ** 2, 0) ** 0.5;
    pv.forEach((v, i, pv) => (pv[i] = v / m));

    // rotation matrix for new pitch axis
    const [x, y, z] = pv;

    const sa = sin(a), ca = cos(a), mc = 1 - ca;
    const xsa = x * sa, ysa = y * sa, zsa = z * sa;
    const xmc = x * mc, ymc = y * mc, zmc = z * mc;

    const Q = [
      x * xmc + ca,  x * ymc - zsa, x * zmc + ysa,
      y * xmc + zsa, y * ymc + ca,  y * zmc - xsa,
      z * xmc - ysa, z * ymc + xsa, z * zmc + ca,
    ];

    // apply local rotation
    updateLocalFrame(Q);
  };

  // key handler
  function keyDown() {
    if (keyboard.ArrowLeft) {
      update(-step, `roll`);
      rotation -= step;
    }
    if (keyboard.ArrowRight) {
      update(step, `roll`);
      rotation += step;
    }
    if (keyboard.ArrowUp) {
      update(-step, `pitch`);
    }
    if (keyboard.ArrowDown) {
      update(step, `pitch`);
    }
    if (!playing) redraw();
  }

  // matrix * vector function
  function mul(M, v) {
    let x, y, z;
    if (v.length === 3) {
      x = v[0];
      y = v[1];
      z = v[2];
    } else {
      x = v.x;
      y = v.y;
      z = v.z;
    }
    return [
      M[0] * x + M[1] * y + M[2] * z,
      M[3] * x + M[4] * y + M[5] * z,
      M[6] * x + M[7] * y + M[8] * z,
    ];
  }
}

// load the code once the custom element loader is done:
customElements.whenDefined(`graphics-element`).then(() => {
  document.getElementById(`graphics`).loadFromFunction(sourceCode);
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/graphics-element/5.0.0/graphics-element.js" type="module"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/graphics-element/5.0.0/graphics-element.min.css" />

<graphics-element id="graphics" title="banking a plane using local roll/pitch and global yaw"></graphics-element>



Putting it all together
And of course, if we want to do something useful with that, we can turn the update into one that checks the plane's local coordinate system with an update in both position (lat, long, elevation), linear momentum (forward and vertical speed), angular momentum (heading and turn rate), as well as global orientation (updating its global yaw if we're not flying perfectly level):
const knots_in_feet_per_s = 1.68781;
const knots_in_kmph = 1.852;
const ms_per_s = 1000;
const ms_per_hour = 3600 * ms_per_s;

const speed = 100;    // let's say we're flying at 100 knots
let lat = 0;          // in degrees of arc
let long = 0;         // in degrees of arc
let elevation = 1000; // in feet
let oldHeading = 0;   // in degrees of arc

function update() {
  // We assume there is something that tells us how
  // many milliseconds passed since the last frame,
  // as a variable called frameDelta, so that we're
  // updating our plane irrespective of frame rate.
  // Whether we're running at 10, 30, 60, or 144 fps,
  // our plane's going to approximately behave the same.

  const [x, y, z] = localFrame.roll;

  // Our vertical speed is purely based on the z-component
  // of our local coordinate system:
  const vspeed = z * speed * knots_in_feet_per_s;

  // And for our forward speed we naively calculate a value based on
  // a triangle where the units... don't match. That's fine: if we
  // wanted realism we'd need to make the plane pick up speed until
  // its forward momentum was counteracted by its drag coefficient,
  // which is *way* more work than we care about here. Instead we're
  // just going to lower the speed the more we pitch up, and increase
  // the speed the more we pitch down:
  const s = sign(vspeed);
  const fspeed = (speed ** 2 - s * vspeed ** 2) ** 0.5;

  // The bank angle of our plane is determined by the z component
  // of our pitch axis, which we use to determine the angle of
  // that axis with the XY plane. Normally that means applying
  // the "soh" rule, i.e. angle = asin(o/h), but in this case our
  // "h" is, by definition, 1, so we get:
  const bankAngle = degrees(asin(localFrame.pitch[2]));

  // Note that this also allows us to play with the step size for
  // our rotation when the user presses left or right: ideally
  // we follow the ICAO "standard turn", where a 25 degree bank
  // angle corresponds to a 3 degrees per second rate of turn.

  // Then, we update our heading based on the angle of our roll
  // axis in the XY plane, with a modulo applied so we're only
  // ever using numbers in the interval [0, 360).
  const heading = (degrees(atan2(y, x)) + 360) % 360;
  const turnRate = ((heading - oldHeading) * ms_per_s) / frameDelta;
  oldHeading = heading;

  // And then we can update our plane's position:
  const km = (knots_in_kmph / ms_per_hour) * frameDelta * speed;
  const pos = getPointAtDistance(lat, long, km, heading);
  lat = pos[0];
  long = pos[1];
  elevation += (vspeed / ms_per_s) * frameDelta;
}

With the getPointAtDistance function calculating GPS coordinates along great circles on Earth (or really, on a sphere with a radius approximately that of Earth. In reality, Earth is not a sphere, of course):
/**
 * Calculate the GPS coordinate [km] kilometers away from the
 * position {lat1, long1} (in radians) when flying a heading of
 * [a] degrees (also in radians), on a sphere with radius [R] in km,
 * and return the result as a new {lat2,long2} (still in radians).
 */
function getPointAtDistance(lat1, long1, km, a, R = 6371) {
  const lat2 = asin(sin(lat1) * cos(km / R) + cos(lat1) * sin(km / R) * cos(a));
  const dx = cos(km / R) - sin(lat1) * sin(lat2);
  const dy = sin(a) * sin(km / R) * cos(lat1);
  const long2 = long1 + atan2(dy, dx);
  return [lat2, long2];
}


I tried re-ordering my rotation matrices, and now the pitch works, but now when I roll it's rotating around a horizontal axis instead of the current pitch and yaw. Is there any way to get both? Also, my plane's orientation is in a list of 3 angles, is that what you mean by orientation vector?

Ah, that's the extrinsic vs intrinsic problem, where the order of operations changes the orientation we end up with, so in this case we want to do things a little differently by not tracking "angles" but "the current local coordinate system" and updating those based on key input. This also has the benefit of immediately having access to your vector of travel. I've updated the answer with some example code.

Ok, I re-adapted the code sample you added to apply the transformation to every single polygon and it works. Thanks a LOT for the help because this problem has had me stumped for pretty much a week, and thanks for being patient since I'm just a high schooler with a high school math background.

I hate to continue an already completed thread, but here's a view of the project I'm working on right now - https://gosoccerboy5.github.io/plane-battle/ - I'm really proud of it so far as almost the entire engine is written by me (the rest being your code). WASD + mouse + space are the controls. Again, thanks!

Nice - you may want to combine a gravity and lift vector though, where gravity is always down, but your lift is aligned with the yaw axis. Then when you run your update cycle, you move the plane both in the direction of your roll axis, and along the resultant vector of gravity and lift. That way when your plane is banking, it will turn (and the more it's banking, the more it will turn until it's upside down and will fall down unless you pitch it correctly)

For completeness, I added a second snippet that shows off adding a global rotation that's stronger the more we're banking, both for future visitors but also perhaps as inspiration for your current work.

And for final completeness, I also added some code that shows how you'd update your plane's position, linear and angular momenta, and orientation during your game loop, because that's generally not easily found in one place, so should hopefully help future visitors too.
